# How does a PXE client know what network its on?

Tags: linux

In PXE Boot one of the first steps is to acquire a IP address via DHCP.

To use DHCP requires you know the broadcast address of your network.

How does this network get initially configured for a PXE client?

Comment: You assign a fixed IP on the local network for the PXE client.

Comment: @DavidPostill: This stands in contradiction to [Daniel B's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1316149) and, as far as my understanding goes, [the docs](http://www.pix.net/software/pxeboot/archive/pxespec.pdf).

Comment: DHCP clients send to 255.255.255.255 using 0.0.0.0 as a "source" when initiating a DHCP broadcast request.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How would it even communicate on the IP layer when it doesn’t have an address? It doesn’t, not really anyway. Instead, it communicates using layer 2.

The broadcast address of any *Ethernet* network is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF. On the IP layer, there’s 255.255.255.255. That’s what’s present on the DHCPDISCOVER packet. This way, you can have a regular UDP listen socket instead of a raw Ethernet socket.

Comment: "_The broadcast address of any Ethernet network is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF._" That applies to any IEEE LAN protocol that uses 48-bit MAC addresses, e.g. Wi-Fi, token ring, FDDI, etc.

Comment: `it communicates using layer 2` this is not correct. Layer 2 does not reach the network level of the Server IP stack. Broadcast layer 2 only transmit the Ethernet frame to all the listeners on one particular Ethernet collision domain. The IP broadcast address is the one that opens the door of the server IP stack.

Comment: Certainly. However, like I wrote, it’s “not really” IP communication. It can’t be. Instead, it makes use of IP packet processing by inserting source and destination addresses that will result in well-defined behavior. Actual addressing is purely done on layer 2.

Comment: You are wrong. Broadcast IP address is definitely IP communication. If that broadcast address is not there the IP layer of the Server does not see the packet. The only particular thing about the broadcast IP address is that it can't be routed.

Comment: I think Pat is  bit right and a bit wrong... in fact broadcast in IP works at layer 3... but DHCP processes all the first steps in L2/ARP/MAC... and only the last step (telling the DHCP server the served IP is accepted in L3/Unicast)... it must be this way because in the beggining it has no IP/L3 stack... other services that do IP broadcast other than DHCP do not have this problem (they already have an IP address) so they can communicate over L3/L4->...

Comment: @ZEE I do not see where I'm wrong. DHCP fixed the problem that BOOTP had where the Servers were forced to deal with L2; `DHCP Servers DO NOT handle L2`; when they answer before the client IP is set they just reply to the client with the broadcast IP. Only the DHCP Client handles L2 when targeting the MAC broadcast i.e. in DHCPDISCOVERY

Answer (score 30):

> To use DHCP requires you know the broadcast address of your network.

No. You only need the local broadcast address 255.255.255.255 (for IPv4), or the multicast group ff02::1:2 (for IPv6). The whole point of DHCP is that it doesn't require *any* prior configuration on the client.

Comment: This is not correct .You also need the MAC broadcast address (Layer 2) because ARP does not work for a broadcast IP address.

Comment: The mapping from IP to MAC broadcast address is presumed to always be known because it's defined by protocol, so it still doesn't need to be configured manually.

Comment: You are wrong. on a booting DHCP client a DHCPDISCOVERY packet must define BOTH level 2 and level 3 broadcast addresses you cannot just define the level 3 broadcast and think any other protocol will discover the target MAC address only having a Broadcast IP destination address

Answer (score 3):

1. The booting firmware discovers the installed NICs
2. The booting firmware discovers each NIC Broadcast MAC address asking the PXE UNDI driver (UNDI GET INFORMATION returning HwType and HwAddrLen) i.e. HwType=ETHER_TYPE HwAddrLen=6 => Broadcast MAC address=FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.
3. The booting firmware initiates the DHCP DORA sequence (DHCPDISCOVERY) announcing itself as a PXE client (DHCP option 60) on the BIOS/UEFI enabled NICs using:

   1. The corresponding previously discovered MAC broadcast address at OSI level 2 (Data Link layer)
   2. The BIOS/UEFI enabled IPv4/IPv6 broadcast address (255.255.255.255/ff02::1:2) at OSI level 3 (Network Layer)
4. The booting firmware finishes the DHCP DORA sequence if a complete DHCP-PXE offer is received defining:

   1. Client IP/Mask address
   2. TFTP server IP address
   3. NBP (Network boot Program)

   Note: If more than one complete offer is received the current standards do not specifically define how the client must select one.
5. The booting firmware sets the NIC IP, TFTP transfers, loads in memory, and executes the NBP.

The layer 2 MAC Broadcast address allows the delivery of the DHCP Ethernet frame to all the listeners within the client's NIC Ethernet collision domain. The layer 3 IP broadcast address is the one that opens the door of the DHCP server IP stack. **Both L2/L3 broadcast addresses are needed**.

When the PXE client and DHCP server are located in different subnetworks the broadcast DHCP traffic is stopped at the router/s then they must enable their DHCP relay agent (IP Helper on Cisco world) taking i.e. the broadcast DHCPDISCOVERY packet, convert it to a unicast DHCPDISCOVERY and route it to the IP address of the defined target DHCP server.

Comment: Nice answer sir.